# jquery select all links except ones having specific class

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm looking for a function to apply a class to all links except the one clicked.

css

```
.foot_active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.foot_inactive {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

html

```
<div class="sitemap">
    <table class="table_site">
        <tr>
            <td class="subsite"><a>op1</a></td>
            <td class="subsite"><a>op2</a></td>
            <td class="subsite"><a>op3</a></td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</div>
```

script

```
$('a:contains("op1")')
    .live('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('foot_active');
        $('a:not(.foot_active)').addClass('foot_inactive');
    });
$('a:contains("op2")')
    .live('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('foot_active');
        $('a:not(.foot_active)').addClass('foot_inactive');
    });
$('a:contains("op3")')
    .live('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('foot_active');
        $('a:not(.foot_active)').addClass('foot_inactive');
    });
```

This script only works for first time you click in link, but not for future clicks.
I think I'm doing something wrong, but my brain seems to be so mad right now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all links inside td with class called .sitemap you could try:

```
$('.sitemap a') .live('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('foot_active');
  $('.sitemap a').not(this).removeClass('foot_active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never removing any classes, so you end up with all links having the inactive class.

You actually don't need the inactive class at all, just remove the active class. This will replace your three event handlers:

```
$('a') .live('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('foot_active');
  $('a').not(this).removeClass('foot_active');
});
```

You might want to use a more specific selctor than `'a'`, like `'.subsite a'` if you have any more links in the page.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't use `.live()` as it is deprecated in jQuery 1.7.

Here is what you're looking for, I hope.

```
$('.sitemap a').click(function(){
  $('.sitemap a').toggleClass('foot_inactive',true).toggleClass('foot_active',false);
  $(this).addClass('foot_active');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

`$('a.foot_active').removeClass('foot_active').addClass('foot_inactive');
$(this).removeClass('foot_inactive').addClass('foot_active');`

...does that do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change all the other elements. An element can have many classes so you only want to toggle the active class.

```
$('.table_site a').addClass('foot_inactive').click(function(){
    $('.foot_active').removeClass('foot_active');
    $(this).addClass('foot_active');    
})
```